# calling function after Inserting row

Tags: python, mysql

I want to call a function after every insert row  but the function is not executed. I am trying to allocate an image to mysql id. I just want to call the function when the row is inserted.

```
def insert_entry(self, camId, camName, vrm, entryDatetime, milliSecs, nationality, filename):
                myFilename = "/tmp/%s" % filename

                sql = """INSERT INTO %s (camera_id, name, plate, datetime, millisecs, nationality, image_name,checked)
                values ("%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s", "%s") """ % (tableName,
                                                               camId,
                                                               camName,
                                                               vrm,
                                                               entryDatetime,
                                                               milliSecs,
                                                               nationality,
                                                               filename,
                                                               checked)
                # print sql
                retVal = self.cursor.execute(sql)

                # Now get the id of the entry we have just created
                sql = """SELECT id FROM %s ORDER BY id DESC""" % tableName
                self.cursor.execute(sql)

This is the function  to be called:

function etCommonGetImagePath($conn, $camName, $id) {
    $serverDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $imagesTop = "/cam_images";


return $webPath;
```

Comment: I think you have tagged the question wrongly: `python` instead of `php`

Comment: @Pynchia This can't be PHP, look at `retVal = self.cursor.execute(sql)`. Looks like a mixture of PHP and python to me at best... but then again, I don't know python.

Comment: This is indeed both python and php